# How to increase between hspace

Tags: spacing, moderncv, cv

How would I increase the vertical space between the first two projects and the second?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}      
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{multicol}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Designer/Developer}
\address{123 Main Street}{Anytown, USA 20192}
\phone[mobile]{(555) 555-5555}                
\email{dasasd@gmail.com}                            
\homepage{www.asdasd.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{asdasdasd}                                    
\social[github]{asdasdasd}                                                                        

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-13mm}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Selected Projects}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://google.com/}{Google}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Googley Google
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdds.com}{asdasdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
        \item asdasdads
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://adsasd.com}{asdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item asdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdd.com}{asdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item adsasdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}     
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what the spacing is now]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

delete the two `\hspace` which are not doing anything and add a vertical space `\bigskip` or `\vspace{3in}` or whatever space you need.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}      
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...
\usepackage{multicol}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Designer/Developer}
\address{123 Main Street}{Anytown, USA 20192}
\phone[mobile]{(555) 555-5555}                
\email{dasasd@gmail.com}                            
\homepage{www.asdasd.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{asdasdasd}                                    
\social[github]{asdasdasd}                                                                        

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-13mm}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Selected Projects}


\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://google.com/}{Google}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Googley Google
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdds.com}{asdasdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
        \item asdasdads
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
   \textbf{\href{http://adsasd.com}{asdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item asdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
   \columnbreak
   \textbf{\href{https://asdasdd.com}{asdasdasdasd}}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item adsasdasdasd
   \end{itemize}
 \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Didn't know that /hspace wasn't necessary.